# Double rendering useEffect reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I try to get async fetch data with a react context provider
I don't understand why there is 2 rendering of child component which use context, with a first initial context state and second with data fetched.
Is there any proper way to avoid it ?

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-chandrasekhar-1w5xv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually normal behaviour. Since your fetch request is async it takes a moment to resolve.

At first your component renders with default data (empty array as per DogProvider.js, line 5) and then once your fetch resolves you update the state of the provider causing it (and its children) to re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Consumers will always re-render when the context changes. In your case it changes as soon as you call `setState` in the Provider with the new data. You could conditionally render the `children` in the Provider while there is no data yet but you can't prevent the children from re-rendering on context updates.

A common pattern is to render a loading indicator until data is available.

You can also wrap your consumers in a custom component that checks if the context is empty but still those will render twice.